# Simplifying script query to single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that selects distinct dates from a MySQL database, and within that results, it sums credits and debits.

See the PHP script.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT date FROM export WHERE exported = '0'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
  $res_sub = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM export WHERE date = '{$row->date}' AND credit = 'credit');
  $row_sub = $res_sub->fetch_object();
  $creditTot = $row_sub->total;

  $res_sub = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM export WHERE date = '{$row->date}' AND credit = 'debit');
  $row_sub = $res_sub->fetch_object();
  $debitTot = $row_sub->total;

  echo "Date {$row->date}: credit > {$creditTot} debit > {$debitTot}<br>";
}
```

But now I need two sub queries, and when when the first query returns 100 rows, it take 100 + (2 * 100) = 300 queries to calculate the result.

I'm pretty sure this can be done in a much nicer way, maybe in just one query! Who knows the answer?

Comment: Is JOIN on the same table possible?

Comment: Of course. Actually, in this instance maybe you don't need that - just SELECT date, SUM(total) FROM export GROUP BY date ??

Comment: I will have a look at joining on the same table! `SUM(total)` won't work because I need to split the `credit` total and `debit` total.

Comment: No join is needed, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date, 
       SUM(IF(credit = 'credit', total, 0)) AS credit_total,
       SUM(IF(credit = 'debit', total, 0)) AS debit_total
FROM export
WHERE exported = 0
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Great, I thought something like this to. But I made a mistake in the SELECT. I did first IF and then SUM, which just gave me the total of credit + debit!

Comment: @Strawberry, why did you edit the answer and changed `exported = '0'` to `exported = 0`?

Comment: Because 0 is an integer, not a string.

Comment: @Strawberry He didn't post his schema, how do you know it's not a string containing `0`?

Comment: @Strawberry, exported is indeed a `int(1)`.